# Why does MOSS sometimes delete an existing user from a site?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm experiencing an issue with a MOSS installation. I am using the Site Settings > Permissions to add an Active Directory account as a valid user of a site. This entails validating that the user account name is correct via the 'Check Names' button, then giving them 'Contribute' permissions. Once this is done they appear as a user on the 'All People' page.

This works fine and the user is able to access the site. At some point in the future (sometimes several days later) the user account is somehow removed as a valid user from the site. This site resides in a test environment so access is pretty well controlled; which has allowed us to rule out someone else going in and removing the user manually. This appears to be something that is being done by the system itself and we have no idea why. We can manually add the user back, but then it will eventually get removed again later.

I have an admittedly limited understanding of SharePoint permissions, but I believe that SharePoint stores valid users in a SQL database and I would assume that when dealing with Active Directory accounts it would be storing the user name and probably the SID. It appears that for some reason this record is later getting deleted out of the database, as the users will suddenly disappear from the "All People" page and will start getting "Access Denied: You are not authorized..." messages when trying to access the site.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Answer (score 0):

Does the active directy link get severed from the test enviroment for some reason like a nightly reboot, daily updates or things like that? What are the differences of the test enviroment from the production enviroment? Is it a virtual machine or is it a physical machine?

This sounds like will have some trouble shooting steps to walk through. Good luck and hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Kevin and I'm the PM responsible for permissions in SharePoint.

I'm not clear what you mean when you say the user account is removed.

Does the user have permissions to the site? 
Do they show up on the 'all people' page?

Comment: Thanks for the response Kevin. I'll update the question to try and clarify some.

Comment: When you go to the permissions page (site settings > advanced permissions.. user.aspx) does the user show up in the list of people who have access to the site?